# How do I use a custom Typescript Declaration file (.d.ts) from within Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, typelite

I am using TypeLite to generate Typescript interfaces from some C# POCOs in a Web API project. This generates a file like:

```
// TypeLite.Net4.d.ts
declare namespace MyNamespace.Models {
    interface InvoiceModel {
        billingPeriodId: number;
        createdDate: Date;
        invoiceId: number;
        invoiceNumber: number;
        organizationId: number;
        paidDate: Date;
        total: number;
    }
}
```

I want to use this file in my Angular project, but I can't seem to find a good explanation of how to do it. I tried various things I've found online including adding it to my `tsconfig.json` in the `files`, `include`, or `typeRoots` sections,  but I haven't found the right way to do it yet. No matter what I do, I still get the error `TS2304: Cannot find name 'InvoiceModel'`. How do I do it?

Comment: Have you tried using the namespace qualified name `MyNamespace.Models.InvoiceModel`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, I have but I'm unsure if I used the right syntax.

Comment: For example for a variable :`let o:MyNamespace.Models.InvoiceModel`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, That doesn't seem to work. How would you import it?

Comment: @adam0101 even if you generate a typescript , you can't import it. Instead I would suggest you should generate typedefinition file as --  module Shapes {  
    export class InvoiceModel {
        billingPeriodId: number;
       
    }
}

Comment: You don't need to import it, these are global namespaces. Try adding a `///` reference to it in the file you use it. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't posted the snippet from where you are using your generated typescript declaration file, and considering to the part of your question

> I tried various things I've found online including adding it to >my tsconfig.json in the files, include, or typeRoots sections"

I am inferring that you are somehow missing to make a reference to the declaration file. That's something which done with [tripple-slash-directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html).

All you need to do is to add the below code wherever you want to use that as the first line.

`/// reference path=".../path/to/file" />`

Comment: That seems to work for intellisense. Is that all that is needed? Or do I need to include this file in the `tsconfig.json` at all for deploying?

Comment: Nope that's it . Make sure to share after you try that.

Comment: I'll let you know if otherwise, but I think that'll do it. I think my confusion stemmed from reading that people were favoring `import` over reference paths. I didn't realize that reference paths are still needed for declaration files.